# 97 Chevy Tahoe , I can hear a sound (bong) coming from Fuel tank,like it’s sucking in. a few seconds after stoping engine

Tags: chevrolet

After driving any distance when I stop about 30 seconds after I shut the engine off I can hear a sound from fuel tank. This sounds like it’s flexing the walls of the tank in a bong sound aif you will it’s not loud but if you listen you will hear it only does it once and the fuel level doesn’t matter If it’s not the cap vent being stoped up something else vent wise must be plugged . I’m wondering where to look & where would be the most likely ?